# Attaching a drain cock for my air compressor to a workbench?

Tags: valve, fitting

I'm looking to extend the pressure release valve on my air compressor so that I don't have to crawl around behind it to let the pressure out. So far my plan is to replace the existing drain cock with a swivel fitting, run a few feet of hose around to the front of my workbench, and mount some sort of valve there. I haven't had any luck finding any sort of valve that could be anchored down properly though. Can anyone point me towards some appropriate parts for this?

(The drain cock does have threads for connecting something, but there's not much clearance between it and the floor which is why I'm leaning towards replacing the current fitting rather than extending it.)

Comment: Are you try to gain access to the over pressure safety valve or the air outlet valve?

Comment: It may not be a good idea to tamper with the compressor, as it could lead to a voided warranty, property damage, injury, and/or death.  However, if the drain cock can accept some type of fitting to extend it, any ball valve rated for the proper PSI should work. Just remember, you'll have to leave the drain cock open and control the drain with the ball valve, so the line between the drain and valve will be pressurized.

Comment: @mike the air outlet valve

Comment: In my compressor the release is on the bottom of the tank so that condensation can drip out as well. In fact, the manufacturer recommendation to drain it *specifically mentions* letting the moisture drip out. With an extension to a workbench height I don't know that you'll get anything dripping out.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want an [automatic compressor drain](http://www.harborfreight.com/automatic-compressor-drain-kit-68244.html). It essentially spurts out a little air (and some moisture/condensate with it) each time the compressor motor cycles on. When working properly, they eliminate the need to manually drain down the tank.

http://www.paragoncode.com/shop/compressor/ has a good explanation of how to install the kit.

Comment: The reviews on that particular kit are pretty bad. But +1 for showing that a solution is available for a reasonable price.

Comment: That's the basic idea, but if there's a way to anchor the valve I can't see it. I'm hoping for something better than zip-tying it in place.

Comment: @BradMace This is a different option for your problem, not a direct answer to your question. Automatic compressor drains remove the requirement to manually open the drain.

Comment: @bob, I'll +1 if you provide a little more detail beyond the link. Links have a habit of going bad over time.

Comment: In that case I could use an explanation of how they work, I've never heard of them before.

Comment: It essentially spurts out a little air (and some moisture/condensate with it) each time the compressor motor cycles on.  When working properly, they eliminate the need to manually drain down the tank.

Comment: Some compressors (such as my DeWalt by Emglo) have this already built-in.

Answer (score 0):

If you can run a tube from the base of your tank up to your bench you should be able to clamp something on [this](http://www.mcmaster.com/#air-flow-control-valves/=j1x8mo) page to open up the tank and most if not all of any standing fluid should come out your hose. You can build or buy something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94QWE.png)

[image]

to mount the valve or hose to your bench. McMaster also would have the hose and any fittings you would need.